# Silverlight Border background colour binding

Tags: silverlight, binding

I would like to bind the colour of the border to the value of a radio button in the border. If the button is true - selected-  I would like to change the default colour of the border from blue to red.

```
<Border x:Name="RibbonMenuRight" 
     Background="Blue" 
     Margin="5">

        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

<RadioButton Margin="0,0,0,10"
         VerticalAlignment="Center"
         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
         GroupName="directions"
         DataContext="{Binding UserSiteSettings}"
         IsChecked="{Binding ExpanderLocation, ConverterParameter=Right,Converter=StaticResource    ExpanderValueToBoolConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />

<TextBlock Text="Right " HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

</StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Any help would be appreciated

regards
mike

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can use an ElementName binding with a converter:

```
<Border x:Name="RibbonMenuRight" 
        Background="{Binding ElementName=ColorRadioButton,Path=IsChecked,Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}}" ...>
    <Border.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:BoolToColorConverter x:Key="BoolToColorConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Border.Resources>
</Border>

<RadioButton x:Name="ColorRadioButton" ... />
```

The converter should return the corresponding brush:

```
public class BoolToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static Brush _trueBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
        _falseBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool isChecked = (value as bool?) ?? false;
        return (isChecked ? _trueBrush : _falseBrush);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```